# Google identity - trigger sign in process on click of custom button

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

I am trying to integrate the new Google Identity API in my project.
I have a custom button lets say a div.

```
<div class="cust1" onclick="triggerGoogleSignIn">Sign in with Google</div>
```

Now I want Sign in to happen only on click of this button.
I checked the documentation and tried `g_id_signin` class renderButton method.

But these methods are replacing my custom button look.

```
triggerGoogleSignIn(){
  ????
}
```

What method should I call?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you solve?

Comment: iam using a work around as of now.
i displayed my google library button over my custom button and i gave opacity 0 to google library rendered button.

Comment: @Prabhu smart trick

Comment: @Prabhu my button is bigger than google's button so there are left some areas that clicking on those areas are not triggering the google's button basically.  and its style can't be changed, any recommendation for that?

Answer (score 6):

In order to get an accesstoken for authorization during your Google API calls, you first authenticate through a OAuth2.0 flow using the following steps:

After loading the library,

```html
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

you initialize the client by calling :

```js
const tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
  client_id: "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID",
  scope: "THE_REQUESTED_SCOPES",
  prompt: "SELECT_A_PROMPT_OPTION", // '' | 'none' | 'consent' | 'select_account'
  callback: handleCredentialResponse // your function to handle the response after login. 'access_token' will be returned as property on the response
});
```

In order to request a new access token, call `requestAccessToken`.

```js
const overrideConfig = {
  prompt: "SELECT_A_PROMPT_OPTION", // '' | 'none' | 'consent' | 'select_account'
}
tokenClient.requestAccessToken(overrideConfig) // open the prompt, overrideConfig is optional
```

Types can be found [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google.accounts/index.d.ts) and installed by executing `npm install --save-dev @types/google.accounts`

---

If you need an id_token for authentication to sign in into your own application, you can opt for the `Sign In With Google` button.

If you want to render your own button and trigger the authentication flow through javascript, [use the following steps](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button#javascript):

Include the client library in your head tag

```html
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

After loading the library, you initialize with your client_id, and set a callback to handle the response after sign in.

```js
function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
  var id_token = response.credential // validate and decode the JWT credential, using a JWT-decoding library
}

window.onload = function () {
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID",
    callback: handleCredentialResponse
  });
}
```

To sign in, just call the prompt.

```
google.accounts.id.prompt();
```

Types can be found [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google-one-tap/index.d.ts) and installed by executing `npm install --save-dev @types/google-one-tap`

Comment: As you said,on load i have initialised the google library and then on click of my custom button i called `google.accounts.id.prompt();` but the google sign in redirect/prompt never opened

Comment: Thanks for the reply as you said i have implemented in the above manner and got the access token in the response.One doubt i have is, in older google lib implementation we were passing access_token and id_token for validation in our backend api.Is there any way to get get id_token similar to access_token

Comment: I updated the answer with steps you need to follow to get an id_token.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
i have followed the above steps but still iam not able to get the expected result.

1.I have a custom button,so if i use renderButton method over my custom button.My button is getting replaced with the google provided button.

2.So as you said, by calling method "requestAccessToken" on click of my custom button i was able to get my access token .Now in similar way,is there any other method which i can call to get the id_token too.since initialising and then rendering the button via "renderButton" is replacing my custom sign in button.

Comment: Don't use the `renderButton` function. Only initialize the client through `google.accounts.id.initialize(...)` and add a 'clickevent'-listener to your custom button in which you call the prompt `google.accounts.id.prompt();`

Comment: As you said on triggering the prompt method i was able to see the "one tap" prompt modal.But if i want like redirect mode (where i select my account and gets redirected to my site) what should i do?

Comment: I guess, you talking about implementing your own OAuth 2.0 flow? Guidelines can be found here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#python

Comment: This is confusing as heck from an implementation standpoint, where their original Sign in with Google was very straight-forward and a clean flow (allowing wide integrations). While this answer kind of sheds some light, I am not sure how long `google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient` will exist after march31st.

Answer (score 0):

when the js of 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client' loaded success
first step, you can set a client to got the result

```
    client = window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
      client_id: clientId,
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
      callback: tokenResponse => handleCredentialResponse(tokenResponse),
    })
```

second step, when you click the button of your customise

`client.requestAccessToken()`

finally, you can got the result in the function of handleCredentialResponse

Answer (score -1):

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview):

> To support a clear separation of authentication and authorization moments, simultaneously signing a user in to your app and to their Google Account while also issuing an access token is no longer supported.

It looks like with Google Identity Services you can get JWT token within browser only with [Sign In With Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview)